# Move rows to another sheet after 6 months

Tags: vba, excel, move

I've been fiddling with this sheet longer than I should.  It is a list of cars that are parked in areas they shouldn't be.  After a period of 6 months, I am trying to get them to automatically "Archive" in another sheet of the workbook.  Essentially I've been trying to find a macro so that after 6 months from the date in the column, it will automatically cut the row and insert it into the next sheet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have toiled on this for 3 days so far and my brain is fried!  Apparently I can't post a screenshot because I need a reputation of 10 (Whatever that means) I can totally email it though.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    If Target.Column = 5 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Value = TODAY() - 180 Then
            Target.EntireRow.Copy
            Worksheets("Archive").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            Target.EntireRow.Delete
            Application.EnableEvents = True

            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If



    If Target.Column <> 5 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Row = 2 Then Exit Sub
    If Left(Target.Offset(0, -1), 1) = "~" Then Exit Sub
    If Left(Target.Offset(0, -1), 1) = "~" Then Exit Sub
    If Left(Target.Offset(0, -1), 1) = "=Row()-1" Then Exit Sub
    Target.Offset(0, -1).Formula = "=Row()-1"

End Sub
```

Comment: so what's your macro now?

Comment: are you mean that you need move the records where the date greater or equal 6 months to another worksheet instead of another workbook? Instead of having screen shot, you can post your code here to let us know where you stuck so that we can help you.

Comment: I posted the code above as requested.  I have the first row on my sheet with headers so I tried to start the macro on the 2nd row.  I'm pretty sure that my brain is just too stretched and I'm doing something very stupid that I'll yell at myself later for missing.  The dates are all in Column E (5th column) and after 6 months they are supposed to move from the sheet they're on "Current Tickets" over to the other sheet "Archive".  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Cause your information is not enough, therefore I suppose your records has been sorted by time and the time is located on Column A

```
Sub MoveRow()
Dim dRow, hRow As Double
Dim s1, s2 As Integer

dRow = 2
hRow = 2
'' number of sheet contain record
s1 = 1
'' num ber of sheet history
s2 = 2

Do While Sheets(s1).Cells(dRow, 1) <> Empty
    ' check if month difference is greater or equal 6
    If DateDiff("m", Sheets(s1).Cells(dRow, 1), Date) >= 6 Then
        Sheets(s1).Cells(dRow, 1).EntireRow.Cut Destination:=Sheets(s2).Cells(hRow, 1)
        Sheets(s1).Cells(dRow, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        hRow = hRow + 1
    Else
        ' if the record is near 6 months, the code will end // reduce time process
        Exit Do
    End If

Loop

MsgBox ("Done")
```

End Sub

Comment: While your code works (with some assumptions), do you know `Dim dRow, hRow As Double` is **NOT** the same as `Dim dRow As Double, hRow As Double`? Rows and Columns are of type Long by the way. You should note that it only works on "oldest on top" from row 2.

Comment: The formula above does work however instead of creating a cumulative list on the separate worksheet, every time I run the macro it overwrites the information on the top rows of Sheet2 instead of adding them below.  Suggestions?

Comment: try this 
`hRow = Sheets(s2).Cells(Sheets(s2).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Where in the formula would you place that?  Where I've put it (different places) it still seems to just overwrite what was originally there.

Comment: Replace the line hRow = 2